# "rucki zucki" - what is the meaning?

Tags: meaning, german-to-english

I hope I got that right : rucki zucki.

I have a CD where a man said :

> Das ging rucki zucki.

Later he tells how crazy is at his new job.

What exactly does it mean?

---

Quick google search just gave [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1CrUWeIxlI). Other links are mostly useless.

Comment: Oooh, it means really quickly... I always thought that was the German equivalent of willy-nilly :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> rucki zucki

or

> ruck zuck

is another way of saying `sehr schnell`. [Here](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=rucki+zucki&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou) is a reference.

In English you could say

> in a jiffy

or

> in no time (at all)

Source: [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=ruck+zuck)

---

There even used to be a German TV game show called [Ruck Zuck](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruck_Zuck) where (at least one part) was about answering quickly.

Comment: Most google results were somehow related to Austria. Your link tells that this is a slang. Is this some kind of austrian slang word?

Comment: @BЈовић I've heard it in Germany as well, but it's kind of an old fashioned expression. You won't hear many young people (if any) use it anymore.

Comment: You are right. My german colleague confirmed. And I just found [this](http://dict.leo.org/#/search=ruck%20zuck&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on). Obviously I was searching for wrong thing. He said that `zak zak` is synonym.

Comment: @BЈовић He probably meant `zack zack`, but yeah, you can use that as well.

Comment: I think "zack zack" is more from Northern Germany.

Comment: "ruck zuck" is quite common, but the only source where I heard "rucki zucki" is the song referenced in the question. Okay, just a personal impressioin ...

Comment: Also in dwds: https://www.dwds.de/wb/ruck%2C%20zuck

Comment: As an Austrian, I don't really perceive any difference between them. But after the Ibiza thing, _zack zack (zack)_ has certainly raised it's standing (https://www.diepresse.com/5733548/ibiza-ist-das-oesterreichische-wort-des-jahres).

Answer (score 2):

Bavarian here. Rucki-zucki is Southern slang (Bavaria/Austria) for „very fast“. „Zack-zack“ is the Northern/„Prussian“ equivalent. A bastardised form „racki-zacki“ exists as well. Used as a command, it means „Get on with it“ — „Aber zack-zack!“ as a slang alternative to „Aber schnell!“

Comment: Here in Berlin, both are used, but differently. I think your answer is wrong.

Comment: Well, I can only speak for my own cultural background. What I said is how it is perceived (and used) in Bavaria. That‘s the thing with slang, it is regionally different. But it makes no difference for the OP‘s question - in that phrase it means „it was done very fast“.

Answer (score 1):

The more common form is "ruck, zuck" without the letter *I*, which is probably why you didn't have a lot of hits.

The English equivalent that comes to mind is "[lickety-split](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lickety-split)"; it conveys both speed and ease, has a similar casual air to it  and has a similar nice vowel repetition as well.

The mentioned Prussian equivalent "zack, zack" has a slightly different meaning. It can be used descriptively as well ("plötzlich ging alles zack, zack"), but true to the Prussian stereotype it is often used as a command. When an officer barks "Aber zack, zack!" the recruit won't dawdle. "Ruck, zuck" doesn't lend itself to that use as well. The "zack, zack" equivalent would be "chop-chop" but it may be a touch harsher.

Answer (score 0):

*Ruck* is a regular noun. Searching in Duden online yields several results including “ruck, zuck”.

Variants of similar **ideophones** exist, *ratz fatz* and *ratz batz* for example. They all refer to the speed of action. Likewise, *in einem Ruck* (in Duden's example sentences) is perhaps better known as *in einem Rutsch* (in one go, all at once). *Rutschen* and *rücken* alternate likewise (to move, make way, step aside). A little different is *zappzarapp*, indicating disappearance as if by magic.

The variation obscures the original signification beyond believe, if there is any. Or in other words, there is no clear relation to the noun.

One has observed (if I recall correctly) that similar words tend to obtain a sense of completeness, see e.g. *bald* or *ganz* in dialect. It maybe coincidence, but a fortunate one in this view, that *Rucksack* can be compared with adverbial *mit Sack und Pack* (with everything, i.e. completely). See also *Puseratze* (?).

A more basic comparison frkm a modern language point of view would be *right* as in *right away*, German *recht* as in *waagerecht* "straight, horizontal". It is not entirely clear if these are related to *upright*, *rectum*, cp. *Rücken*, *zurück*. An obsolete verb *rutzen* (to run, or flee) also comes to mind, cp. *Rückzug*. A different option is *rush*, and *rustle*, indicative of Dutch (cp. *hustle*, Dutch *hutselen, husselen*, etymonline; add Ger. *huschen*, or better *hetzen*). I guess *fast* presents itself, but nobody *gives a fack*.